# AWS Lambda - Python - Filter Attribute with Price List

Tags: python, aws-lambda, price

I using python + lambda in AWS for get price with Attribute.

Follow this code. I get 4 result.

But the result have Full information.

 Could you advise to me how to filter the result ? How to print 4 result and only some attribute (example: vcpu, Ram, network, os, price)

Thanks for all :)

```
import json
import boto3
client = boto3.client('pricing')
response1 = client.get_products(ServiceCode='AmazonEC2',
    Filters=[
        {
            'Field': 'instanceType', 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Value': 'r5.xlarge',
        },
        {
            'Field': 'operatingSystem', 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Value': 'Linux',
        },
        {
            'Field': 'vcpu','Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Value': '4',
        },
        {
            'Field': 'networkPerformance', 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH','Value': 'Up to 10 Gigabit',
        },
        {
            'Field': 'location','Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Value': 'EU (Paris)',
        },
        {
            'Field': 'usagetype', 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Value': 'EUW3-BoxUsage:r5.xlarge',
        },
    ],
    FormatVersion='aws_v1',
    MaxResults=100,
)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return response1
```

Comment: share `response1 ` (as text) and explain what is the expected output.

Comment: The output too long - i cannot post in there. Could you help run by yourself ? Thank for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below

```
import ast

REQUESTED_ATTRIBUTES = {'servicecode', 'storageMedia', 'location', 'productFamily'}

products = {
    'FormatVersion': 'aws_v1',
    'NextToken': '57r3EXAMPLEujbzWfHF7Ciw==:ywSmZsD3mtpQmQLQ5XfOsIMkYybSj+vAT+kGmwMFq+K9DGmIoJkz7lunVeamiOPgthdWSO2a7YKojCO+zY4dJmuNl2QvbNhXs+AJ2Ufn7xGmJncNI2TsEuAsVCUfTAvAQNcwwamtk6XuZ4YdNnooV62FjkV3ZAn40d9+wAxV7+FImvhUHi/+f8afgZdGh2zPUlH8jlV9uUtj0oHp8+DhPUuHXh+WBII1E/aoKpPSm3c=',
    'PriceList': [
        '{"product":{"productFamily":"Storage","attributes":{"storageMedia":"SSD-backed","maxThroughputvolume":"320 MB/sec","volumeType":"Provisioned IOPS","maxIopsvolume":"20000","servicecode":"AmazonEC2","usagetype":"CAN1-EBS:VolumeUsage.piops","locationType":"AWS Region","location":"Canada (Central)","servicename":"Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud","maxVolumeSize":"16 TiB","operation":""},"sku":"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U"},"serviceCode":"AmazonEC2","terms":{"OnDemand":{"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U.JRTCKXETXF":{"priceDimensions":{"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7":{"unit":"GB-Mo","endRange":"Inf","description":"$0.138 per GB-month of Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1)  provisioned storage - Canada (Central)","appliesTo":[],"rateCode":"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7","beginRange":"0","pricePerUnit":{"USD":"0.1380000000"}}},"sku":"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U","effectiveDate":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","offerTermCode":"JRTCKXETXF","termAttributes":{}}}},"version":"20170901182201","publicationDate":"2017-09-01T18:22:01Z"}',
        '{"product":{"productFamily":"Compute","attributes":{"storageMedia":"SSD-backed","maxThroughputvolume":"320 MB/sec","volumeType":"Provisioned IOPS","maxIopsvolume":"20000","servicecode":"AmazonEC2","usagetype":"CAN1-EBS:VolumeUsage.piops","locationType":"AWS Region","location":"Canada (Central)","servicename":"Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud","maxVolumeSize":"16 TiB","operation":""},"sku":"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U"},"serviceCode":"AmazonEC2","terms":{"OnDemand":{"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U.JRTCKXETXF":{"priceDimensions":{"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7":{"unit":"GB-Mo","endRange":"Inf","description":"$0.138 per GB-month of Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1)  provisioned storage - Canada (Central)","appliesTo":[],"rateCode":"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7","beginRange":"0","pricePerUnit":{"USD":"0.1380000000"}}},"sku":"WQGC34PB2AWS8R4U","effectiveDate":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","offerTermCode":"JRTCKXETXF","termAttributes":{}}}},"version":"20170901182201","publicationDate":"2017-09-01T18:22:01Z"}',
    ]
}
result = []
for entry in products['PriceList']:
    data = ast.literal_eval(entry)
    temp = {}
    for k, v in data['product']['attributes'].items():
        if k in REQUESTED_ATTRIBUTES:
            temp[k] = v
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

output

```
[{'storageMedia': 'SSD-backed', 'servicecode': 'AmazonEC2', 'location': 'Canada (Central)'}, {'storageMedia': 'SSD-backed', 'servicecode': 'AmazonEC2', 'location': 'Canada (Central)'}]
```

Comment: Can we get also [term] [OnDemand] ? example Price and Description ?

Comment: Try to modify the code and get it. Let me know.. (does it work for you?)

Comment: Thank. Still now it working. But i try to edit more for get price and description. I will share to you status soon.

Comment: I try to edit code then the result is shorter but also cannot get only Description and Price.

Comment: @NiNoMax share the exact output you are looking for based on `products ` in my answer.

Comment: `[{'vcpu': '4', 'operatingSystem': 'Linux', 'networkPerformance': 'Up to 10 Gigabit', 'instanceType': 'r5.xlarge'}, {'vcpu': '4', 'operatingSystem': 'Linux', 'networkPerformance': 'Up to 10 Gigabit', 'instanceType': 'r5.xlarge'}, {'vcpu': '4', 'operatingSystem': 'Linux', 'networkPerformance': 'Up to 10 Gigabit', 'instanceType': 'r5.xlarge'}, {'vcpu': '4', 'operatingSystem': 'Linux', 'networkPerformance': 'Up to 10 Gigabit', 'instanceType': 'r5.xlarge'}]`

Comment: This is result - i try to add more price and description. Do you have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Hello. Now i already done it. Thank so much

Comment: @NiNoMax I am glad I managed to help. You can accept the answer now.